# Java: Assignment in Char

Tags: java, arrays, command, char

I have a program and I need to understand it, but I don't understand two lines of it. 
Okay so there is one-dimensional array - int [] names,
and two chars - char let1, let2.
Now, there is a command:

```
char let1 = names[i].charAt(names[i].length()-1);
char let2 = names[i+1].charAt(0);
```

What does that mean?

Comment: This code wouldn't compile if `names` is actually an `int[]`. It looks pretty clear that it's a `String[]`. Now which *specific* bit of that code don't you understand?

Comment: Are you sure that 'names' type is int?

Comment: length is an attribute if it is int[], charAt is a method and length is also a method for String.

Answer (score 1):

`let1` is assigned the last character of `names[i]` and `let2` is assigned the first character of `names[i+1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char let1 = names[i].charAt(names[i].length()-1);
```

It means find out the `string` at index `i` of `String` array `names` and from that `String` extract out the character at the last index of that String. And then assign that character value to the `char` variable `let1`.

```
char let2 = names[i+1].charAt(0);
```

It means extract out the String at index `i+1` from `String` array names and from that `String` extract out the `character` at first index (`0`) . And then assign that character value to the `char` variable `let2`.